# I have a question about prepositon in the sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When you are in a exam,you should avoid doing noises.

Is this preposition usage right?

Comment: The preposition is okay, but the rest of the sentence has a few problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition does work, but could be better as

> When you are *sitting* a**n** examination . . .

We don't **do noises**, but **make** them. The duplication of **you** can also be avoided:

> When sitting an examination, you should avoid making noises.

Or, inverting the sentence and using a different preposition:

> You should avoid making noises **during** an examination.